# Issue while converting HTML to PDF using itextSharp for < symbol

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am trying to convert HTML content to PDF using itextSharp in .net application using c#. While doing so m gettting my content trucated after '<' symbol. For conversion I am using following line:

HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlContent, null);

This is the code snippet with need to add referece 'itextsharp.dll' reference

Following is Code Snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreatePDF();
        }

        static void CreatePDF()
        {
           string fileName = string.Empty;

            DateTime fileCreationDatetime = DateTime.Now;

            fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", fileCreationDatetime.ToString(@"yyyyMMdd") + "_New" + fileCreationDatetime.ToString(@"HHmmss"));

            string pdfPath = "D:\\" + fileName;

            using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                //step 1
                using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 140f, 10f))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
                        //pdfWriter.PageEvent = new ConsoleApplication1.ITextEvents();

                        //open the stream
                        pdfDoc.Open();

                        {
                            Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello world. Checking Header Footer", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 16));
                            para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                            pdfDoc.NewPage();
                            string str = "<b>Try<</b>";

                            StringReader TheStream = new StringReader(str.ToString());

                            List<IElement> htmlElementsh = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(TheStream, null);

                            IElement htmlElementh = (IElement)htmlElementsh[0];
                            pdfDoc.Add((Paragraph)htmlElementh);
                        }

                        pdfDoc.Close();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //handle exception
                    }

                    finally
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet?

Comment: Parsing HTML content directly to PDF can cause unexpected behavior, some tags are not supported and cause inappropriate results or corrupted file. Why is there an extra < after Try?

Comment: I can't understand why you are using IElement to insert normal string and why have you created a paragraphp 'para' if you are not adding it to pdfDoc? what how much data you are getting in your pdf and what is getting truncated?

Comment: put your html content within panel
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
panel.RenderControl(hw);

Comment: @Codeek : I am using IElement coz its requirement of my application , the pdf I am trying to generate is pdf of 3-4 pages containing various HTML tables n u can ignore that those first 2 lines. Those are in actual code. N after '<' my that line gets truncated e.g. m having Line 1:"Line 1 < Testing " I ll get in pdf just "Line 1"

Comment: @Manish : can u plz help with your code in detail coz m not having any panel and using above format is mendatory for me.

Comment: try changing < with any other symbol say | or - or :. Like I said, It may consider < as beginning of a tag it doesn't identify.

Comment: Hi, all finally I got solution I used '&lt;' instead of '<' because it treating as opening bracket n look for closing 1 ie. '>' .

Comment: Thank u all for help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly use &lt; instead of < and use &gt; instead of >.